# Abort trap: 6 on Mac when trying to run program with quicksort

Tags: c, gcc, runtime-error

So, I'm trying to run the following C program, and all I get when I run it is an error that says:

> Abort trap: 6

Any ideas why? This only happens when I run the quicksort algorithm. I think it has something to do with the recursion, but it should work fine, so I don't know what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_DIM 30

int partition(char**, int, int); 
void quickSort(char**, int, int);

int main()
{
    char **array;
    array = (char**) malloc(6*sizeof(char*));
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (char*) malloc(MAX_DIM*sizeof(char));
    }
    strcpy(array[0], "ok");
    strcpy(array[1], "bye");
    strcpy(array[2], "then");
    strcpy(array[3], "yeah");
    strcpy(array[4], "lets");
    strcpy(array[5], "go");
    quickSort(array, 0, 5);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void quickSort(char **a, int l, int r)
{
    int j;
    if( l < r )
    {
        j = partition( a, l, r);
        quickSort( a, l, j-1);
        quickSort( a, j+1, r);
    }
}

int partition(char **a, int l, int r) {
    int i, j;
    char pivot[MAX_DIM], t[MAX_DIM];
    strcpy(pivot, a[l]);
    i = l; j = r+1;
    while(1)
    {
        do ++i; while( strcmp(a[i], pivot) <= 0 && i <= r );
        do --j; while( strcmp(a[j],pivot) > 0);
        if( i >= j ) break;
        strcpy(t, a[i]); strcpy(a[i], a[j]); strcpy(a[j], t);
    }

    strcpy(t, a[l]); strcpy(a[l], a[j]); strcpy(a[j], t);
    return j;
}
```

Comment: we're just missing the headers and `MAX_DIM` value...

Comment: MAX_DIM is 30 and I'll add the headers now

Comment: When you say "gcc error which says Abort trap: 6", do you mean an error from gcc at compile time, or a run-time error?

Comment: Run-time error, my bad

Comment: time to step through a debugger.. Are you sure it breaks while quicksorting? Where do you free everything?

Comment: gdb says this line steps out of array bounds:  do ++i; while( strcmp(a[i], pivot) <= 0 && i <= r );  I think you need to put i <= r first, but that's assuming the rest of your logic is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Logic Bug

```
(a && b) != (b && a)
```

in general, for C/C++.  They are equal if and only if the evaluations of `a` and `b` are **independent** of each other.

In the specifications, there exists a *short-circuit optimization* so that if `a` is false, `b` will never be evaluated.  Hence, the logical-and operation is **not commutative**, if expressions `a` and `b` are not independent of each other.

Your code is a *perfect example* of lack of independence between your expressions - ordering does matter.

**Change:**

```
do ++i; while( strcmp(a[i], pivot) <= 0 && i <= r );
```

**To:**

```
do ++i; while( i <= r && strcmp(a[i], pivot) <= 0 );
```

**Output:**

```
bye
go
lets
ok
then
yeah
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!